# 401 Unauthorized - when try to hit rest service of Spring application

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

When try to hit rest webservice of spring application getting 401- Unauthorized when passing Authorization header in request. I dont want spring to authenticate or validate my header but I want to send Authorization header to endpoint.

web.xml

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<display-name>Test Tool</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/SpringConfig.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/v1.2/transfers/**" access="permitAll" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/home" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
    <user-service>
    <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </user-service> 
    </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

I am try to call following service from client tool /v1.2/transfers/****

Spring-Config.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />   
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.demo" />   
    <bean name="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" /> 
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable http pattern for the REST api endpoint like below.

```
<http pattern="/v1.2/transfers/**" security="none"/>
```

Comment: Thks for the response, When I try with this I'm getting 404.

Comment: whatever you put in pattern those urls will be open for security means you can access without login.so just put the url.so here /v1.2/transfers/ whatever url comes after /v1.2/transfers will be open from security.

Comment: 30-Oct-2018 13:07:32.753 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
30-Oct-2018 13:07:32.757 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/testtool-1.4.0-SNAPSHOT] startup failed due to previous errors